# jQplot treat each item as a new one

Tags: arrays, jqplot

I am using jQplot for a bar graph but I've run into problem.

Here is some sample data:

var s2 = [["28",425, null], ["23",424], ["24",417], ["25",390],["26",393], ["27",392], ["28",369]];

The problem i have is there are two values the same e.g. 28 and jQplot treats this as the same item is there a way to make it treat this as a separate value?

Answer (score 1):

Break your data and labels into two separate arrays (data and ticks), then use the CategoryAxisRenderer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    ticks = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'One', 'Two', 'One'];

    data = [12,14,6,21,17, 21];

    var opts = { 
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: jQuery.jqplot.BarRenderer
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: ticks
            }
        }
    };

    plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chart1', [data], opts);

});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/KGp5a/1/).